# How to call a getter method in the Data Assignments I/O in a jbpm task?

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn, kie

In a jbpm process i recieve an object (of class Employee) from a rest call.
I made a class in jbpm to handle this Employee and access all the properties

In the OnExit Action of the rest task I write the following code

```
kcontext.setVariable("processEmployee", myEmp);
```

in this way I put in `processEmployee` (a process variable) the employee retrieved from the rest call and stored now in a local variable. The above assignment works fine.

Now, it would be handy to access the employee properties in a simple way, such as by calling directly `processEmployee.getEmail()`

I can call `processEmployee.getEmail()` in an onExit action event and assign the returned value to another process variable of type string named `employeeEmail`, and then I can use this variable in the Assignmeent Data I/O panel.

But it would be much easier to avoid creating the `employeeEmail` variable and call `processEmployee.getEmail()` directly into the panel like this:
[image]
but the above does not work since the code is seen as a string.

Is there a way to call a method (such as `myEmp.getEmail()`) there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `#{processEmployee.getEmail()}`.

The `#{...}` works as a sort of escape.