# How to call a setter method in the Data Assignments I/O in a jbpm task?

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn, kie

I have a process in jBPM. The process has a Human Task.
Also there are Data Objects: SrcData, CalcInter.

In the Human Task's Assignment Data I/O panel I need to read properties from the objects in Data Inputs section, and write a calculated variable in the property of CalcInter object in Data Outputs section (see picture).

[Screenshot of Assignment Data I/O panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZGMl.png)

Objects' properties reading in Data Inputs works as intended. As suggested here:
[How to call a getter method in the Data Assignments I/O in a jbpm task?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67401670/17620940)

But writing Object property in Data Outputs in such way doesn't work.
I've tried:

```
#{CalcInter.setAxx(axx)}
#{CalcInter.setAxx((int)axx)}
#{CalcInter.setAxx(#{axx})}
```

How to solve this? (And why is it so complicated?)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the issue can be solved by using **MVEL** notation instead of pure Java.

If in Data Outputs as a Target we use following expression:

```
#{CalcInter.axx}
```

The jBPM engine correctly updates the object property.

(How to use a Java style in the case and if it is possible — I still don't know.)